# Input Submit Buttons Missing Values due to Sequencing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm banging my head into a brick wall. My guess is that this is an issue about what comes first, but I can't seem to figure out the order that this should happen.

Basic Scenario:
This is a PhoneGap app (But this is particularly a JavaScript question). One index.html file and one .js file to send ajax calls to PHP files who run to a database and return info to be used in the app.

jQuery and jQuery Mobile are both being used as well so the index.html is broken down into page elements that I can go back and forth between (this might be relevant)

So far so good. After signing in the user goes to a page where a set interval function is run which uses ajax to query a php and in turn a database getting an answer and sending it back down the chain and causing an action.

One of those actions is "Gee whiz there's a new question, I'll set all the variables into local storage and then change the page via:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#pageX", {transition:"slide", changeHash:false});
```

Now I have a function that runs .on("pagebeforeshow":

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pageX", function () { 
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("score");
        document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("category");
        document.getElementById("mob_question_question").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("mob_question_question");      
        return false;
    });
});
```

This all works a treat.

Now for the tricky bit I have in the .html four forms containing a input type="submit" each:

```
<form id="question1"><input id="answer1" type="submit" value="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a"></form>
<form id="question2"><input id="answer2" type="submit" value="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a"></form>
<form id="question3"><input id="answer3" type="submit" value="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a"></form>
<form id="question4"><input id="answer4" type="submit" value="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a"></form>
```

That's the background, now the question. I'm looking to set the values of the buttons to the answers sent down in the ajax call (I've checked to make sure the right info is being sent)

I couldn't seem to implement any JavaScript in the pagebeforeshow function as it would not fill the buttons, but managed to figure out I needed to put the JavaScript within  tags after the buttons in the html. I've also included the JavaScript I'm using to randomize where the answers appear for everyone.

```
<script>
    var answers = [window.localStorage.getItem("correct"), window.localStorage.getItem("wrong1"), window.localStorage.getItem("wrong2"), window.localStorage.getItem("wrong3")];
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    var answer1 = answers[index];
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    var answer2 = answers[index];
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    var answer3 = answers[index];
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    var answer4 = answers[index];
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    window.localStorage.setItem("answer1", answer1);
    window.localStorage.setItem("answer2", answer2);
    window.localStorage.setItem("answer3", answer3);
    window.localStorage.setItem("answer4", answer4);

    document.getElementById("answer1").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer1");
    document.getElementById("answer2").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer2");
    document.getElementById("answer3").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer3");
    document.getElementById("answer4").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer4");
</script>
```

After all that what is happening is the whole shebang is working with the exception that when the buttons come up they come up with the last loaded version of answers in the localStorage and will stay all through the questions (i.e. question changes but the answers are the same).

Like I said at the beginning I'm guessing this is to do with loading up the values of the submit buttons in the wrong order or this JavaScript is being missed after the first run through. Any suggestions on how to go about trouble shooting this mess would be whole heatedly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile enhances the button so that the text is no longer the value of the input but rather the html inside a DIV created by jQM.  So you just need to tell jQM to refresh the widget after setting the value:

so instead of

```
document.getElementById("answer1").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer1");
document.getElementById("answer2").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer2");
document.getElementById("answer3").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer3");
document.getElementById("answer4").value = window.localStorage.getItem("answer4");
```

Use jQuery and call .button("refresh")

```
$("#answer1").val(window.localStorage.getItem("answer1")).button("refresh");
$("#answer2").val(window.localStorage.getItem("answer2")).button("refresh");
$("#answer3").val(window.localStorage.getItem("answer3")).button("refresh");
$("#answer4").val(window.localStorage.getItem("answer4")).button("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gd5n4/)**

Comment: This was almost there, I was messing up my use of events and where I could put script tags and have localStorage refresh. Long story short I went through combination after combination until it worked. But thanks for the refresh tip.